# Copy users from one Joomla db to a slightly newer one

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, phpmyadmin

Assuming I have an earlier copy of a Joomla database can I simply copy the jos_users, jos_userkeys, jos_usernotes, jos_userprofiles and jos_usergroup_map tables to a newer copy of the database - by using the phpadmin export feature, then reimporting into the newer database?

It would save me some time in using Akeeba to restore the entire site. (I had used Arra Usermigrate to export the users and neglected to export the User IDs. Then when I imported the users into the new site an extension that uses the IDs to match the user to their submissions didn't work because the imported users have different IDs. Not a big deal to restore from backup and start again but this would save me some time. Thanks.

Comment: You can export specific tables from your database and import them. Do this using PHP MyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I ended up doing yesterday after testing a few times. It worked fine.

Comment: Mark your answer as correct please (otherwise it'll remain an "unanswered question" and get bumped by the site periodically).